# Why do I need a use statement in this perl program?

Tags: perl

I have a perl subroutine called `foo` that is in file `C.pm`.  `C.pm` is in directory `B` and that is in directory `A` as follows:  `A > B > C.pm > foo`

I'm trying to call the foo subroutine from another file.  If I do the following it works:

```
use A::B::C qw(foo);

//Code here

foo($temp)
```

However, the following doesn't work

```
//Code here

A::B::C::foo($temp)
```

Why not?  I thought I didn't need to include the `use` statement if I explicitly wrote out the path when calling that subroutine.

Comment: do remember that `//` is not a comment in Perl, use `#` for a comment

Comment: @JoelBerger You got me...That should be a `#` sign.  You can tell, I'm a Java programmer at heart

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `use` does two things:

1. It `require`s a file, which parses, compiles and executes it
2. It calls the `import` method on the new module, which can install subroutines in your current namespace.

You have to somehow execute a module before using subs defined in it.

If you don't want to import any subroutines or other symbols, you can give `use` the empty list:

```
use A::B::C ();
```

Comment: To take this a step further, the reason that using the fully qualified name sometimes works is that if ANY OTHER module has loaded the module in question (via use or require) now you can use the fully qualified name. Check `%INC` to see what has already been loaded.